# C++ returning nested class with template on base class problem

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I am trying to create a list object, with the iterator class nested inside to understand how it works.
In some method, I am trying to return an iterator object but it doesn't work.
I created an example to show the problem :

```
// CLASS A
template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
        class B;
        A(){}
};

// CLASS B
template <class T>
class A<T>::B
{
    private:
        int varB;

    public:
        B(B& b);
        B(const int&);
        B returnThis();
};

template <class T>
A<T>::B::B(const int& value)
{
    varB = value;
}

template <class T>
A<T>::B::B(B& b)
{
    varB = b.varB;
}

template <class T>
A<T>::B A<T>::B::returnThis()
{
    return *this;
}

// MAIN

void main()
{
    A<int>::B classB(10);
}
```

The error is near those lines:

```
template <class T>
A<T>::B A<T>::B::returnThis()
```

The compiler tells me I am missing a ; before A::B::returnThis()

I am trying to solve this problem for days and I can't find a way to make it work...
I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `typename`:

```
typename A<T>::B
```

To indicate to the compiler that `A<T>::B` is a type. Here's a [good explanation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) why.

What `B` is depends on what `A<T>` is, this is called dependency. Any time you are getting a type out of a class or struct, and it's dependent on a template, you'll need to use `typename`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a look @ typename!